# AngularJS signal that sort is complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a very large data set that needs to be sorted. I've got the sort working completely, the only issue is that when a sort button is pressed, nothing happens until the sort is done. On the smaller data sets it's not a problem because it's almost instantaneous.

I have a function to change the sort parameters but I'm not sure what, if any signal is emitted from angular to signal that the sort/render is complete. This signal would be used to hide/destroy a spinner.

The directive template:

```
<div data-ng-if="dataModel">
    <div class="drillHeader" style="width:{{(dataModel.depth * 20) + 200}}px;">Groupings</div>
    <!-- dynamic sort buttons -->
    <div class="drillHeader drillSorter"
         data-ng-repeat="c in dataModel.columns"
         data-ng-class="{drillBorderLeft : $first, asc: asc == true && sortBy == 'totals.'+c, desc: asc == false && sortBy == 'totals.'+c}"
         data-ng-click="changeSort(c)">{{makePrettyKeyNames(c)}}</div>
</div>
<div data-ng-repeat="d in dataModel.data | orderObjectByDeep:sortBy:asc" data-ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}">
    <div class="drillSection collapsed" data-ng-class="{noCollapse: dataModel.depth == 1}">
        <div class="drillItem" style="width:{{(dataModel.depth * 20) + 200}}px;">
            <span class="drillHead">{{makePrettyKeyNames(d.keyName)}}:</span> {{d.key}}
        </div>
        <div class="drillData" data-ng-repeat="key in dataModel.columns" data-ng-class="{drillBorderLeft : $first}">{{formatData(d.totals[key], key)}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="drillCollapse" style="display:none;" data-ng-if="dataModel.depth != 2" data-ng-include="'level2template'" onload="data=d.metrics"></div>
    <div class="drillCollapse" style="display:none;" data-ng-if="dataModel.depth == 2" data-ng-include="'finalLevelTemplate'" onload="data=d.metrics"></div>
</div>
```

The function to change the sort parameters (inside the directive):

```
scope.changeSort = function(key) {
    var index = 'totals.' + key;
    if(index == scope.sortBy) {
        scope.asc = !scope.asc;
    } else {
        scope.sortBy = index;
        scope.asc = true;
    }
    // start spinner here
}
```

I'm using a custom sort filter but I couldn't figure a way to have it send a signal.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('orderObjectByDeep', function() {
    return function(items, field, reverse) {
        var properties = field.split(".");

        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            filtered.push(item);
        });
        filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a;
            var y = b;
            for (var i in properties) {
                x = x[properties[i]];
                y = y[properties[i]];
            }
            return (x > y ? 1 : -1);
        });
        if (reverse)
            filtered.reverse();
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

I am by no means an angular expert but I can usually find the answers, but this one has me stumped. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case instead of sorting the list in the view I would rather sort it inside of your controller. You can use the `$timeout` service to sort your data asynchronicly.

So in your view you had something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in sortedList">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
<div ng-if="!isSorted">Loader</div>
```

And in you controller:

```
isSorted = false;
$scope.sortedList = [];
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.sortedList = $filter('orderObjectByDeep')(dataModel.data, sortBy, asc);
  isSorted = true;
});
```

Comment: The wiping of the sortedList is not needed. Removing it has the advantage that my collapses (treed data) are left open. I placed the controller portion inside the changeSort function with an additional timeout to help the spinner show up earlier.